# Cannot disable memcache in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In environments/development.rb have

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

In environments/production I have

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

However, when in development mode, some content still gets returned from cache. For example:

```
translated = Rails.cache.fetch(md5(txt + session[:lang]), {:expires_in => 240.hours}) do
     Translation.where("enstr = ? and lang = ?", txt, session[:lang]).limit(1).first
end
```

will sometimes return a cached value instead of always hitting the database. I was not able to determine a pattern, like it would only happen for certain values or at a specific time of day and so on. It just happens apparently at random. I am using dalli 2.7.6.

Comment: How do you know it's coming from that cache? Can you paste log lines that illustrate the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: I know because I see either a database query or a cache hit, when I should only see database queries in development mode.

Comment: The `perform_caching` setting applies to page, fragment, and result caching, things that are persisted to files for the view to use. What I think you're seeing is [SQL Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching), where identical queries within a request cycle are not re-run.

Comment: It's not SQL caching. That code is inside a helper.

Comment: Post the log so we can be sure.